# Is there a way to call a constructor with optional parameters, while setting the parameter value to 'unspecified'?

Tags: kotlin

If I have methods below:

```
fun testMethod(
  test1: Int = 5,
  test2: String = "hello",
  test3: Boolean = true,
) {
  // do some stuff
}
fun callerMethod(
  caller1: Int,
  caller2: String,
  caller3: Boolean,
) {
  // do some stuff
  testMethod(test1 = caller1, test2 = caller2, test3 = caller3)
}
```

Is there a way to modify the callerMethod above, so that its parameters caller1, caller2, caller3 are optional, and if they are not provided, then it testMethod will be called using the default values set for test1, test2 and test3?

I don't want to do this, because then there will be two sources of truth for the default values:

```
fun callerMethod(
  caller1: Int = 5,
  caller2: String = "hello",
  caller3: Boolean = true,
) {
  // do some stuff
  testMethod(test1 = caller1, test2 = caller2, test3 = caller3)
}
```

I am hoping I could do something like below, but 'unspecified' is not supported, I think:

```
fun callerMethod(
    caller1: Int? = null,
    caller2: String? = null,
    caller3: Boolean? = null
) {
    // do some stuff
    testMethod(
        test1 = caller1 ?: Unspecified,
        test2 = caller2 ?: Unspecified,
        test3 = caller3 ?: Unspecified
    )
}
```

And I can't create global variable with the default values as testMethod belongs to 3rd party library and I cannot modify it.

To give some context, I'm currently learning Android Jetpack Compose, their base UI components is are functions with average 10 parameters with lots of default values. I am creating my own UI components which calls to them, and running into this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with reflection, for example:

```
fun callerMethod(
    caller1: Int? = null,
    caller2: String? = null,
    caller3: Boolean? = null,
) {
    val testMethodRef = ::testMethod
    val testParams = testMethodRef.parameters
    // testParams is a List of parameters of testMethod
    // testParams[0] is test1 and so on
    val testArgs = buildMap {
        if (caller1 != null) { put(testParams[0], caller1) }
        if (caller2 != null) { put(testParams[1], caller2) }
        if (caller3 != null) { put(testParams[2], caller3) }
    }
    // Now we create a Map of parameters that we want to change to arguments
    testMethodRef.callBy(testArgs)
    // And call testMethod with those arguments only
}
```

You might have to add a dependency to `build.gradle.kts`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("reflect"))
}
```

Comment: Haven't get to try it yet, looks promising thanks for this! But it seems to make it look less readable for the thing it is trying to achieve though :(